# Pressure as the magnitude of the reaction force

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image]

Here $\vec{F}$ is the reaction force caused by the interaction of the fluid particle on the surface and another.

I don't think the two parts I have highlighted in green tally with one another.

If $\vec{F}=p\vec{n}dS$ this implies that

$\vec{F}.\vec{\hat n}=pdS$ and $\vec{F}.\vec{\hat n}=|\vec{F}|$  so

$|\vec{F}|=pdS$ which is different from what is written in the first green underline

Comment: The last equation seems to be correct to me except that I would write $d\hat F$ instead of $F$, but the first one is missing something, pressure is certainly not the magnitude of the force, unless you're talking about unit area explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivation shown in the paper is a real mess. Not only he forgot the area, but he doesn't work well with the differentials. The first green underline should read $|\vec{dF}|=pdS$ and the second one $\vec{dF}=p\vec{n}dS$

Comment: Why would you write $\vec{dF}$ as opposd to $\vec{F}$?

Comment: because both sides must be the same "size". The area in infinitesimal, so the force will be too. If you want the force on a specific finite area (instead of an infinitesimal one), you need to integrate both sides.